# discord.py event encountering error saying missing positional arguments

Tags: python

ok so i am developing this discord bot and here is my code and the error it just gave me. it would be super awesome if anyone could help me with this issue. thanks in advance:

````
import discord
import random


client = discord.Client

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("ready")
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith("generate password"):
    alp = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

    for i in range(8):
      randm = random.random()
      final = ""
      final = final + alp[randm]
      
    await message.channel.send(final)
my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
client.run(my_secret)```





Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    @client.event()
TypeError: event() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'coro'
````

Answer (score 0):

Probably something to do with intents, not entirely sure, but this code works with the latest discord.py version (update if it isn't).

```
import discord
import random

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("generate password"):
      alp = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

      for i in range(8):
        randm = random.random()
        final = ""
        final = final + alp[randm]
        
      await message.channel.send(final)

client.run('token')
```

Not sure if mandatory but you might also want to enable the message intent in the [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/)
[image: screenshot]